# What is Mackenzie mimimg at Jim Harper at the near ending ot the season 1 premiere?

Tags: dialogue, the-newsroom

I just watched the season 1 premiere of *The Newsroom* and I was wondering if anyone can tell me what Mackenzie is mouthing to Jim Harper?

What are her exact words?

I cannot find the suitable clip for the episode but if you've seen the episode you'd know but let me be more precise in description: After they finish reporting their 'breaking news' everybody is leaving for the day. When Don and Maggie are leaving together Jim is watching Maggie as she leaves. Mac catches Jim do that and when Jim has Mac's attention she mouthed her words so that Don and Maggie couldn't hear her. She was mouthing her words when Jim cut her short and said:

> JIM: I don't know what you're miming.
>   Mac: (After a pause) You're fine.

I think Mac meant that he's good just the way he is when she said "you're fine." What I want to know, what did Mac say when she mouthed her words? She sarted with pointing out to the couple that just left saying "they". That's all I can describe.

I've been looking for its scripts on the net but no luck so far. I'm also looking for this video, because I'd like to see it, but no luck. There are many videos but not this one. I know it is very vague when there isn't any clip but I'll keep searching for the clip and update it if I find it. Meanwhile I was hoping to get lucky if anyone has seen this episode and knows what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's not clear.

A lipreader might be able to make sense of it but it seems that it's intended to be somewhat confusing.

[image]

However, an [**early draft of the script**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65189401/Untitled_Aaron_Sorkin_Cable_News_-_Aaron_Sorkin__HBO_.pdf) (where Don was called *Steve*) indicates that Mac was suggesting that Jim was a better man than Don/Steve for Maggie.

[image]

Comment: @Pauli_DHey! I just finished reading this draft before I saw your post. Thankyou so much for helping. While reading I wasn't sure if this scene will be there as it is slightly different. I wasn't even sure if this is what exactly is said on TV. But thanks again for clarifying it to me :)

Comment: @Pauli_D I'm glad I can rely on you people if ever I have a query about this serial, right? Sorry to bother, though.